# Induced matrix p-norm example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm struggling to understand induced matrix p-norms. Our lecture notes have used the example:
$$A := \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\0 & 3 & 0\\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{3}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$
In this example we're told that we have computed the induced matrix p-norms of A for $p \in \{1,2,\infty\}$ and found them to be 3.

There isn't any working out to how this was achieved, would anyone be able to go through the working.

I understand that in this case $|A|_p$ := sup $\frac{|Ay|_p}{|y|_p}$ for all $p\in [1,\infty]$ but the notes have made it very unclear as to what y is in this case, and what exactly the notation of $|Ay|_p$ means.

Comment: What do you know about the $p$ norm in case of $p\in\{1,2,\infty\}$? What have you tried?

Comment: I was unsure of MathJax working in the comments so i've added it as an edit to the post.

Comment: $y$ here is an arbitrary vector. We're taking a supremum over all non-zero vectors $y \in \Bbb R^3$, in this case.

Comment: @Goshawk: MathJax works as in the question. But editing the question with more details you know is the better practice anyway. And $|y|_p$ is the $p$ norm on $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you how you did things in class, but here is a way to compute each of those $p$-norms.

$p=1$: we want the maximum absolute column sum.  That is,
$$
\|A\|_1 = \max_{j} \sum_{i=1}^m |a_{ij}|
$$
The first column sum is $3/2 + 1/2 = 2$.  The second is $3$. The the third is $2$.  So, the maximum is $3$.

$p=2$: For any symmetric matrix, $\|A\|_2$ is the maximum absolute value of the eigenvalues.  In this case, the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (in absolute value) is $3$.

$p = \infty$: We want the absolute row-sum.  That is,
$$
\|A\|_{\infty} = \|A^T\|_1 = \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|
$$
since $A$ is symmetric, we get $3$ again.